# Navbar: background on active Site

Tags: html, css, header, navbar

i want a navbar that mark for example on page index.html the navbar link with the text Home with a backgroud identical with the hover effect.

As follow my code..

CSS:

```
.header {
border-bottom: 6px solid black; 
padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
background: #D11B1B; 
position:fixed; 
top:0; 
left:0; 
z-index:2000; 
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
}

.nav ul a {
background-color: none!important;
padding: 20px 2px 20px 0px;
font-size: 40px;
}

.nav ul a:hover {
background-color: black!important;
border: 1px solid white;
padding: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
width: 100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header class="header">
<div class="nav">
<ul>
<a href="index.html" class="nav-active">Home</a>
<a href="werbung.html">Werbung</a>
</ul>
</div>
</header>
```

Thx.

Comment: Did not understand anything you wrote!

Comment: Why not add .nav-active{...} in your css?

Comment: @Gacci What? my code?

Comment: @LordRixuel when i make a class whit this content: .nav-active {
background-color: black!important;
border: 1px solid white;
}     then its completly wrong formated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a specific button/link in the navbar on each page, then you can specify give the button that links to the current page an "active" class.

```
<body>
<div class="nav">
<a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
<a href="page2.html">Home</a>
<a href="page3.html">Home</a>
</div>
</body>
```

And then in your css, specify specific styles for ".nav a.hover" to make the active page look different on the navbar. You can add whatever styles you want, for example adding a bottom border, changing the color, or whatever you want to do.

```
.nav a.active{
color:red;
}
```

If you want to make the buttons change color when you hover the mouse over them, then use ".nav a:hover" and add whatever styles you want.

```
.nav a:hover {
color:dark-blue;
}
```